# Why isn't my newly installed Euro lock cylinder working?

Tags: doors, lock

We have just moved into a new apartment and wanted to change the lock cylinder. Taking out the old one was not a problem. But when we put the [new cylinder](https://www.tesa.es/en/site/tesa/products/cylinders-and-master-key-systems/high-security-cylinders/tk100-cylinder/) in, the latch won't extend nor retract. Quite sure the size of the new lock is the same as the old one as it fits and everything, so we have no idea what went wrong. We tried the new lock cylinder alone without installation and it turns fine, though there's a tiny glitch in between the movement.

Did we get a faulty lock cylinder or it was something wrong in the installation?

---

Additional note:
The lock doesn't work well just by itself, I tried again today it kind of worked in the door, but was really hard to turn at some point.
https://youtu.be/y_AClXwbC4s
When I put back the old one, it works fine and smooth.

Comment: Does the cylinder operate normally when it's not in the door?

Comment: If you re-install the old cylinder, does it still work?

Comment: Can you post photos of the old and new *tailpieces*? (i.e. the widget on the back of the cylinder core that engages with the latch) It sounds like the new cylinder's tailpiece isn't mating with the lockset's innards properly.

Comment: I have added more information in the question and this video I took should explain better https://youtu.be/y_AClXwbC4s Thanks

Comment: @Zan -- it'd be better if you added still photos of the tailpieces into the question